# Google spreadsheet: Value parameter can not be parsed for number

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm using this script to integrate price change inside my google sheet. The command I'm performing is:

```
=VALUE(Right((Index(ImportHtml("http://bigcharts.marketwatch.com/quickchart/quickchart.asp?symb="&B5&"", "table"),3,2)),7))
```

Where B5 contains: `BTOU` and this is the value I got returned.

As a result I see following error:

> `VALUE parameter ': +0.02' cannot be parsed to number.`

Would be much appreciated for the help.

Comment: Welcome ! I posted an answer. Let me know if it works for you !

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result

Answer (score 1):

You can use another Right() to get the last 5 digits.

```
=Value(Right(Right((Index(ImportHtml("http://bigcharts.marketwatch.com/quickchart/quickchart.asp?symb="&B5&"", "table"),3,2)),7),5))
```

Answer (score 0):

I had been using this formula for years.

After trial and error this one works.  It just changed the 7 and the end to a 6.  Dont ask me why!

```
=VALUE(Right((Index(ImportHtml(CONCATENATE("http://bigcharts.marketwatch.com/advchart/frames/frames.asp?symb=",B5,"&insttype=Fund"), "table"),3,1)),6))
```